# Configuring IIS Express failed

Tags: iis-express

When I try and open an existing website, Visual Studio opens this error:

> Initializing the applicationhost.config file failed.  Copying the applicationhost.config file to \servername\folder\folder2\folder3... failed.  The network name cannot be found.

The problem is that the \servername cannot be found.  How do I change that servername to the one that does exist?

`\\servername` is offline, so how is visual studio even using that server?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying open website which is located in network folder?

Comment: @PankajKapare yes I am

Comment: Do you (logged in user or user under which Visual Studio is running) have write permission on that network folder?

Comment: @PankajKapare yes I have write permission on that folder.

Comment: That's strange because somehow Visual Studio is not able to copy applicationhost.config file to that folder. One workaround is copy website to local machine and give a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is if you install IIS after installing visual studio, VS may not have access to IIS related files like Applicationhost.config file. That is why uninstalling and reinstalling VS solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling and reinstalling VS, this issue was resolved.